# Wordpress reset password and log in user issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin for my wordpress page, and I want to create a custom reset password (to be different then the wp admin reset page).

I created a php file which is a shortcode, and this is how I reset the password:

```
get_currentuserinfo();
$userID = $current_user->ID;
wp_set_password( $_POST['pass1'], $userID );
clean_user_cache($current_user->ID);
wp_clear_auth_cookie();
wp_set_current_user($current_user->ID);
wp_set_auth_cookie($current_user->ID, true, false);
update_user_caches($current_user);
```

But if I refresh the page the user is logged out. I dont think I can do a redirect here, since this is a shortcode this gets executed after the headers are sent. Any tips on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the user using Javascript (`window.location.assign()`)

Comment: No, because in your code you have setted up new user cookies (wp_set_auth_cookie).

Comment: i have tried it, but user is logged out after redirect